# If $A,B$ are diagonalisable, does $AB$ diagonalisable imply $BA$ diagonalisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

As discussed [in this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/311346/173147), $AB$ and $BA$ always have the same characteristic polynomial, but not necessarily the same minimal polynomial.

This means that $AB$ diagonalisable does *not* imply $BA$ diagonalisable, as shown by the example
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
On the other hand, we know that if both $A,B$ are *invertible*, then the statement is true.

As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1823135/173147), it is also the case that the non-zero spectrum of $AB$ and $BA$ is always the same.

I am looking for an answer to the slightly different question: *assuming $A,B$ are both diagonalisable, is it true that $AB$ diagonalisable implies $BA$ diagonalisable?*
The counterexamples I've seen (the post linked above and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3169668/173147)) all involve at least one non-diagonalisable matrix, hence my question.

If the above is not true, what about the more restrictive case of $A,B$ both normal? Or maybe the case with $AB,BA\neq0$?

Comment: regarding your final line -- "what about the more restrictive case of , both normal"  -- this is an easy yes.  If A, B normal and AB is normal, then BA must be normal.  It's a nice result and fairly simple exercise.

Comment: $A,B$ invertible does not imply $A,B$ commute!

Comment: @DavidPeterson Correct thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counterexample:
\begin{aligned}
AB&=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1}\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 1&1&0\\ 0&0&1}=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1},\\
BA&=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 1&1&0\\ 0&0&1}\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&1}=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&1}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: well, this covers all bases, but still also kind of follows the same patterns as the other cases. You fix one of the two matrices not being diagonalisable by using $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ rather than $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$. This however still results in $AB=0$, and so you embed the matrices into a larger one acting trivially on a third mode to fix it. I wonder, can you also find an example with two diagonalisable *not mutually diagonalisable* matrices? This would make the $AB,BA\neq0$ property more "genuine"

Comment: @glS I suspect that this is impossible, but I haven't any proof yet.